# Collection Type Field with a File Field to generate their own respective download link

Tags: forms, dom, collections, symfony-2.1

I having a problem with getting/generating the download link from a Collection Type Field in a form, inside the collection type I have a File Field. Everything works fine with uploading files but in order to generate their own respective download link is where I'm stucked right now.

Is there any way to get the url from the file field? What can I do?

```
<ul>
        <li><ul class="preguntas" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.seguimientos.vars.prototype)|e }}">
            {% for pregunta in form.seguimientos %}
            <li>
                {{ form_row(pregunta.seguimientoTipo) }}
                {{ form_row(pregunta.fecha_entrega) }}
                {{ form_row(pregunta.fecha_prorroga) }}
                {{ form_row(pregunta.descripcion) }}
                {{ form_row(pregunta.loQueSeEspera) }}
                {{ form_row(pregunta.isRecibido) }}
                {{ form_row(pregunta.contactos) }}
                {{ form_row(pregunta.comentarios) }}
                {{ form_row(pregunta.archivo) }}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
    </ul></li>
```

This is what I got with {{ dump(pregunta.archivo.vars.value) }}

```
object(Proxies\__CG__\daci\contratosBundle\Entity\Document)#596 (5) { ["__isInitialized__"]=> bool(true) ["id":protected]=> int(160) ["path":protected]=> string(44) "1feb865f404cba0567e075c76bf6c0b402621e8e.png" ["file":"daci\contratosBundle\Entity\Document":private]=> NULL ["temp":"daci\contratosBundle\Entity\Document":private]=> NULL }
```

What I want to get is "path" from the object and create the download link

Answer (score 0):

To access to the field I just needed to use {{ pregunta.archivo.value.path }}

From that I created the download link